# how can htmlagilitypack check if nodes exist on webpage?

Tags: html-agility-pack

Using `Vb.net` and `HtmlAgilityPack` is there a way to check if the node exists on the webpage before selecting the node ?

While running my program, if the node doesn't exist at all on the page, I am getting a null exception error message.

I don't want to use

```
If firsttag(0).InnerText IsNot Nothing Then
```

as by using this, the program is already trying to get the value of the node.

I would like to scan the webpage first to see if the node exists

```
Dim firsttag As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = docnews.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[(@class='byline')]")
```

Is there anything like

```
if firsttage(0) search does not exist then Continue For Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether firstTag returns `Nothing` or if it returns an empty list:

```
 If (firstTag IsNot Nothing and firstTag.Any() and firstTag.First().InnerText IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, the software is not entering the If statement, it generates null exception on the IF satement: `Dim firsttag As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection = docnews.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[(@class='byline')]") If (firsttag(0).InnerText IsNot Nothing And firsttag.Any()) And firsttag.First().InnerText IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show("If Working") End If`

Error Message: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestSoftware.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: The order is important. Plus, remove the `firstTag(0).InnerText`, it's handled by the `firstTag.Firs().InnerText`